# C# file iteration performance - worth bypassing string.IsNullOrEmpty for performance?

Tags: c#, string, performance

Currently writing a file parser that runs through data files line by line and cleans the data. Performance is an important consideration for this application. The user assigns labels to the data columns to let the process know which column represents what kind of data - i.e. which is a surname field, which is an address field, which is a telephone number and so on.

I just finished writing a bunch of code that cleans phone numbers, and applied it like this:

```
public void CleanPhoneFields(FileRow row, List<Mapping> mappings)
{
    // this will return empty if there's no field mapped with the "Telephone Number" tag
    string phoneNumber = GetValueByAssignedLabel(row, mappings, "Telephone Number"); 

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber))
    {
        CleanTelephoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }
}       

public void ProcessFile(FileContents fileContents)
{
    foreach (FileRow row in fileContents.FileRows)
    {
        // does other cleaning functions too
        CleanPhoneFields(row, fileContents.Mappings, fc);
    }
}
```

Then I realised that by checking the phone field on a row by row basis was unnecessary - it was true for the first line in the file, it'd be true for all of them. So I might be better off doing this:

```
public void CleanPhoneFields(FileRow row, List<Mapping> mappings)
{
    // this will return empty if there's no field mapped with the "Telephone Number" tag
    string phoneNumber = GetValueByAssignedLabel(row, mappings, "Telephone Number");
    CleanTelephoneNumber(phoneNumber);
}       

public void ProcessFile(FileContents fileContents)
{
    bool firstLine = true;
    bool cleanPhoneNeeded = false;

    foreach (FileRow row in fileContents.FileRows)
    {
        if(firstLine)
        {
            cleanPhoneNeeded = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetValueByAssignedLabel(row, fileContents.Mappings, "Telephone Number"));
            firstLine = false;
        }

        if(cleanPhoneNeeded)
        {
            CleanPhoneFields(row, fileContents.Mappings, fc);
        }
    }
}
```

I still have to go and get the field value for each row, so all I'm "saving" in this case is getting rid of a call to string.IsNullOrEmpty on each row. On the flipside, the second code is (to my eye) slightly less readable, and has lost a little defensive coding.

Is getting rid of string.IsNullOrEmpty going to save me much in the way of processing cycles? Is it worthwhile for the small downsides of the second approach. Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Have you measured? Anyway, I would expect `String.IsNullOrEmpty` to execute in microseconds. Comparing two values to zero and dereferencing the first to get the second should not take long.

Comment: @MartinLiversage no - that was going to be my next step. I asked first partly out of curiosity and partly to make sure that I wasn't just going the wrong way about this, period.

Comment: The second is more efficient. If you can trivially determine in advance that you don't need to do work, do so and don't do the work - that seems eminently sensible to me.

Comment: [Obligatory Eric Lippert link. If you've got two horses...](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the affect of the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` call is negligible.

The benefit of your second solution though is that it eliminates the whole `CleanPhoneFields` call, and more importantly, the `GetValueByAssignedLabel` call which seems to be the slowest part (except the actual `Clean` part which cannot be avoided **when needed**).

However, I would refactor the original procedure slightly different, keeping the tradeoff between readability and performance.

First, I would make the `CleanPhoneFields` method to return `bool`:

```
public bool CleanPhoneFields(FileRow row, List<Mapping> mappings)
{
    // this will return empty if there's no field mapped with the "Telephone Number" tag
    string phoneNumber = GetValueByAssignedLabel(row, mappings, "Telephone Number"); 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber)) return false;
    CleanTelephoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    return true;
}
```

Then the main method could be like this:

```
public void ProcessFile(FileContents fileContents)
{
    bool cleanPhoneFields = true;
    foreach (FileRow row in fileContents.FileRows)
    {
        if (cleanPhoneFields)
            cleanPhoneFields = CleanPhoneFields(row, fileContents.Mappings, fc);
        // Other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Stopwatch class in the System.Diagnostics namespace and you can measure the time it takes your program to execute in milliseconds.

Try with and without the null and empty checker (Although ill doubt there is much of a measurable difference)

More info found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`string.IsNullOrEmpty` has practically no cost (nothing you can be worried about anyway)

What you might wanna do on the other hand is declaring the "Telephone Number" as a `private const` field to prevent it's creation every time you call `CleanPhoneFields` method.

You can also use `string.Intern` to prevent that ...